# Post an internet link with the appropriated picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I want to share an article from our website on facebook, but we are facing two problems:

1/ Almost all the time, the suggested pictures are pictures from the website but from other pages, not from the article I want to share. (And the picture has a straight relation with the subject of the article)

2/ this type of link http://www.kacileo.fr/blogs/4/1wblmb-la-face-cach%C3%A9e-de-nos-faiblesses can't be shared on facebook because we don't have any proper title and picture.
Try by yourself and you'll see! But this link works on linkeIn, Viadeo...

So, do you have any answers? Is there any people who have the same issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) when displaying the preview of your link. The best way to tell the OGP what to display is adding some meta tags to the `<head>` of your page.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Example Title" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/exampleimage.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Example description" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com">
```

[More information on Facebook's website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I checked the codes of the page and I can see all those meta tags. According to my internet ingeneer, the page is well coded, so the problem must come from facebook... 

This problem seems very complicated to me.